# MySQL check if a condition is true from last to start and if stopped return

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements

I really love to know how this is possible without doing a for loop.My way is lame,I check the last then take the previous check again and add this values to an array and when the condition wasn't true anymore I return the array.This is not pure sql and uses php for loop so it's not very performant,I need to do this with sql.Example:

```
chatTable:
from_id    to_id     msg                  time
2          1         Hi                   2 days ago(as timestamp)
1          2         Hello                yesterday
1          2         How you doing?       today
```

So here we are going to take all the messages that id 1 sent from the latest until It's not him anymore.

```
1->2 How you doing  = (true)
1->2 Hello  = (true)
2->1 Hi = (false)
```

so

```
return
1->2 How you doing
1->2 Hello
```

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  You need a column that specifies the ordering.

Comment: @GordonLinoff It's just an example I have created_at timestamp as another column.

Comment: The table should also have a primary key. Does it have one?

Comment: @stevemoretz . . . Provide meaningful sample data and desired results.  Your question does not show the timestamp.

Comment: @GordonLinoff it's ascending.I edited the question thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First way is to order the recrods in desc order of timestamp. Then look for patterns in your data such that the next_from_id is same as that of the current_from_id.
If they are different then ignore.

If this looks correct the following can be done

```
select * from (
    select from_id
           ,to_id
           ,timestamp
           ,lead(from_id) over(order by timestamp desc) as next_frm_id
      from chatTable
      )x
 where x.from_id = x.next_frm_id
```

Comment: Hi thank you it gives this error:
[42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(order by created_at desc) as next_frm_id ' at line 5

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the last set of messages that are for `from_id = 1`.  That would be:

```
select ct.*
from chatTable ct
where ct.from_id = 1 and
      ct.timestamp > (select max(ct2.timestamp)
                      from chatTable ct2
                      where ct2.from_id <> 1
                     );
```

This assumes that the most recent message if from id 1.

Comment: Hi Thank you for the answer I tried your code it returns no result.

Comment: @stevemoretz . . . This should return what you are asking for in the question.

Comment: Please check this picture:https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWN6v.png